# Setupbld not performing as required

Tags: installation, wix

I am using "setubld.exe" (by wix) to merge .exe and .msi file

It executes pre-requisite file .exe file and then it throws error that Setup.msi file not found.

Can anyone please guide me on this.

Comment: There really isn't enough information provided to help. What is  command-line you are running setupbld.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i was not able to make it work as per my requirement, I switched to [dotnetinstaller](http://dotnetinstaller.codeplex.com/) and was successful in merging msi and exe